# Why does my image rotate in Laravel when I select a picture to be uploaded?

Tags: php, laravel, exif, intervention

When I select an image to uploaded it rotates 90 degrees even before I select upload. The picture has the correct orientation on my phone and on my computer. I used the intervention orientation but it still rotates? I looked at other posted on stack overflow and they say I only need to read it from exif but it doesn't work when I use the orientation method.

```
public function updateProfilePicture(Request $request)
{
    try 
    {

        $blurImage = null;
        $image = 'images/demo.jpg';
        $is_video = Auth::user()->is_video;
        $blur_check = $request->blur_check;

        if($request->old_profile) 
        {
            $image = $request->old_profile;
        }

        if($request->is_video_profile == 1)
        {

            if($request->profile_video) 
            {
                $image = $this->uploadProfileVideo($request->profile_video,$request->start_time);
                $is_video = 1;
            }

        }
        if($request->profile_pic)
        {
            if($request->blur_check){
                $image = $this->uploadBase64Images($request->profile_pic);
                $image = $image->orientation();
                $blurImage = $this->blurImage($request->profile_pic,$request->blur_val);
            }
            else{
                $image = $this->uploadBase64Images($request->profile_pic);
                $image = $image->orientation();
            }

            $is_video = 0;
        }
        else if($request->blur_check){  
            $image = $request->old_profile;
            // $image = Auth::user()->profile_picture;
            // $blur_image = Auth::user()->blur_prof_picture;

            $ext = explode('.', $image);
            $fullPath = url('/').'/'.$image;
            $arrContextOptions=array(
                "ssl"=>array(
                    "verify_peer"=>false,
                    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                ),
            );  
            $img = file_get_contents($fullPath,false,stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)); 

            // Encode the image string data into base64 
            $data = base64_encode($img);

            $base64Img = "data:image/$ext[1];base64,".$data;
            $blurImage = $this->blurImage($base64Img,$request->blur_val);

            $is_video = 0;
        }
        if($is_video == 1) 
        {
            Session::set('video_message', 'Profile video has been uploaded successfully');
            return redirect()->route('view.my.profile');
        } 
        else
        {
            if(empty($request->profile_pic)){
                $this->user_image->updateOrCreate(['file' => $request->old_profile],[
                    'file'          =>  $image,
                    'blur_file'     =>  !empty($blurImage) ? $blurImage :null,
                    'is_blur'   =>  !empty($blur_check) ? 1 : 0,
                    'blur_val'   => !empty($blur_check) ?$request->blur_val:0,
                    'user_id'       =>  Auth::user()->id
                ]);
            }else{
                $this->user_image->create([
                    'file'          =>  $image,
                    'blur_file'     =>  !empty($blurImage) ? $blurImage :null,
                    'is_blur'   =>  !empty($blur_check) ? 1 : 0,
                    'blur_val'   => !empty($blur_check) ?$request->blur_val:0,
                    'user_id'       =>  Auth::user()->id
                ]);
            }

            $this->user->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update([
                'profile_picture'   =>  $image,
                'is_video'          =>  $is_video,
                // 'blur_check'     =>  $blur_check,
                // 'blur_prof_picture'  =>  !empty($blurImage) ? $blurImage :null,
                'camera_capture'    =>  0
            ]);
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => 'Profile Picture has been updated successfully'));
        }

        // if(!empty($blurImage)) {



        // }else{
        //  $this->user->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update([
        //      'profile_picture'   =>  $image,
        //      'is_video'          =>  $is_video,
        //      'blur_check'        =>  $blur_check,
        //      'camera_capture'    =>  0
        //  ]);
        // }

            // echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => 'Profile Picture has been updated successfully'));


    } 
    catch(\Exception $e) 
    {
        dd($e);
    }
}


protected function uploadBase64Images($file)
{
    try{

        if ($file == null) {
            return '';
        }
        if (Auth::check()) 
        {
            $username = Auth::user()->username;
            $path = 'files/'.trim($username).'_'.Auth::user()->id;

        }
        else 
        {
            $path = 'files/profile';
        }

        if(!file_exists(public_path(). '/' .$path)) {   

            mkdir(public_path(). '/' . $path,0777, true);

        }

        list($imageType, $file) = explode(';', $file);
        list(, $file) = explode(',', $file);
        list(, $imageType) = explode(':', $imageType); 
        list(, $imageType) = explode('/', $imageType);

        $base64Content = base64_decode($file);

        $image = Image::make( $base64Content );


        if (!isset($imageType) && $image->mime() == 'image/jpeg') {
            $imageType = 'jpg';
        }  

        if (!isset($imageType) && $image->mime() == 'image/png') { 
            $imageType = 'png';
        } 

        $fileName = public_path(time() . '_' . $imageType);
        $image->stream();

        $destinationPath = $path . '/' . time() . rand(100, 1000) . '_' . $imageType . '.' . $imageType;
        $image->save($destinationPath);

        if ($image) {
            return $destinationPath; 
        } 


        return $image;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are still alot of functions in your example code which dont explain themselves, so would be nice if you uploaded them as well. Like `$this->uploadBase64Images($request->profile_pic)` or `$image->orientation()`. At which point did you check the image for it's orientation?

Comment: @RobBiermann $image->orientation is where it checks it out.

Comment: @RobBiermann I just updated the code that shows what that function is doing.